# Running PostgreSQL docker image on a different Port

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run a PostgreSQL instance on a different port, by setting the port as argument in '-p' however it does not seem to have any effect.
Ex:

```
docker run --name db_Dev -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=postgresDev -p 7432:7432 postgres:10.5
```

Output:

```
2019-09-15 17:50:29.494 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-09-15 17:50:29.494 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
```

Any idea how to set a different port for it?
Thanks

Comment: Within the container, the port remains the same, what you need is this `-p 7432:5432`.By doing so, you'll be able to connect to localhost:7432

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to run multiple Postgres instances or change the listening port of Postgres then follow this.

```
docker run --name db_Dev -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=postgresDev -p 7432:5432 postgres:10.5
```

Here `-p 7432:5432` is mapping port 5432 inside your Postgres container on to port 7432 of your host.

Or you can change the listening port 5432 of Postgres by setting environment variable `PGPORT` to `7432`.

```
docker run --name db_Dev -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=postgresDev -e PGPORT=7432 -p 7432:7432 postgres:10.5
```

*Note: If `PGPORT` doesn't work try `POSTGRES_PORT`.*

Comment: PGPORT was what I was looking for! The other StackOverflow posts just mentioned the remapping (option 1) of what you mentioned, but didn't go into option 2 that you gave with running postgres itself on a different port. So thank you!

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get docker to forward port 7432 to 5432 (using -p 7432:5432). I could only get it to work when I set both -p 7432:7432 and PGPORT. Does PGPORT also add some other networking settings like /tcp or something that forwarding from 7432:5432 doesn't do?

Comment: So does it have to be 5432 (the default listening port of Postgres) and no other value?

Comment: If using `bitnami/postgresql` image then the environment variable is `POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER`. More environment variables see: [postgresql-env.sh](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/371f6977c73ad9edfca4e68ddf02009188d48232/bitnami/postgresql/14/debian-11/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/postgresql-env.sh#L39)